# ##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '' in azure devops kubernetes task

Tags: azure-devops

Starting: Bake manifests
Task : Deploy to Kubernetes
Description : Use Kubernetes manifest files to deploy to clusters or even bake the manifest files to be used for deployments using Helm charts
Version : 0.178.0
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://aka.ms/azpipes-k8s-manifest-tsg
##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod ''

Comment: Can someone let me know how to fix this error.

Comment: Hi, could you share the build definition here? Then set the variable system.debug to true and share the detail log here. According the the error message, this issue seems to be related to field Manifests, this field is the path to the manifest files to be used for deployment.

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Yes. The issue is explained in https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13911 and https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13911.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your sharing, could you please convert to comment to answer and [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)